# Referencing in PHP

Tags: php, reference, pass-by-reference

Looking at referencing in PHP is pretty much confusing me, can anyone explain to me how this would work:

```
private $TestArray1 = Array()
private $TestArray2 = Array()

private function test1(){
$this->test2($this->TestArray1);
$this->test2($this->TestArray2);
}

private function test2($Array){
$this->test3($Array);
}

private function test3($Array){
$Array[0] = 1;
}
```

Where would I be putting the "&" in this, if I wanted to have the private variables TestArray1 and TestArray2 be edited, after it is set in function test3?

Comment: You must have come from C or C++, no?

Comment: Nope, have never touched those languages before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private $TestArray1 = Array()
private $TestArray2 = Array()

private function test1(){
$this->test2($this->TestArray1);
$this->test2($this->TestArray2);
}

private function test2(&$Array){
$this->test3($Array);
}

private function test3(&$Array){
$Array[0] = 1;
}
```

So you need to specify `&` in the function declaration, and pass parameter as-is.

Comment: Would you use the & in the parameter if you wish to return a reference? ie/ return &$TestArray1;

Comment: @Phoenix: nope, you also need to place `&` in declaration like `function & bla()` and return variable as-is

Comment: and sorry lastly, what about referencing inside the same function (have to do this due to switch case) example: http://codepad.org/tZNCEnQf

Comment: @Phoenix: `$a = & $b;` --- now both `$a` and `$b` refer to the same data

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior in php 5.3 is to pass objects by reference.  You can use the & symbol to force primitive types to be passed by reference too, though you normally won't have any reason to do this.

Your example is potentially confusing, as you don't seem to be inside of a class, so the private modifiers don't make sense.  No reason to pass a member variable into a method, as the method could access it directly itself.

Hope that helps.

EDIT: And I also should point out that apparently arrays don't count as object for the "default pass by reference." That is, the & is required here: codepad.viper-7.com/LBcr4m

Comment: How about the fact that `test3` have no idea what array it works with?

Comment: Ah sorry it would be:

<?php
Class Test{
//code
}
?>

New to PHP, so still not 100% sure about the terminology - I don't normally code with variables, that can store classes, but using "primitive types" so I can just use integer for loops, and I do realize I could use ForEach, but then I can't control that with numbers (alteast I cannot think of a way).

Comment: Yeah that's true.  And I also should point out that apparently arrays don't count as object for the "default pass by reference."  That is, the & is required here: http://codepad.viper-7.com/LBcr4m

Comment: "pass objects by reference" No, that is not pass-by-reference. That is passing a reference, by value, similar to Java, Python, Ruby, etc.